# Zeta polynomial of the Boolean Lattice

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, boolean-algebra, combinatorial-proofs

The task at hand is to compute the zeta polynomial $Z(B_k, n)$ of the Boolean Lattice in $k$ elements, which is the lattice formed by the subsets of $\left\{1, \dots, k\right\}$ under inclusion. The zeta polynomial $Z(B_k, n)$ counts the number of *multichains* $t_1 \leq \dots \leq t_n = \{1, \dots, k\}$ of length $n$ in the lattice $B_k$. A multichain is simply a chain with element repetitions allowed.

A direct combinatorial approach outlined in Example 3.12.2 from [[Enumerative Combinatorics]](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf) shows that $Z(B_k, n) = n^k$. Is there a bijective approach towards that result?

P.S: This is homework so please do not post full answers.

Comment: What is a multichain?

Comment: @WilliamElliot A multichain is a chain that is allowed (but not required) to have repeated elements. For example, in $B_3$, $(\emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{1, 2\})$ is a chain, and $(\emptyset, \{ 1 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{1, 2 \})$ is a multichain.

Comment: There are infinitely many finite multichains in any lattice.

Comment: As there are $2^n$ subsets of {1,2,.. n}, $B_k$ has $2^n$ elements.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: I added some more info. I am specifically interested in multichains of length $n$.

Comment: Formed by the subsets of {1,2,..  n} implies all the subsets.   Is that your intention?

Comment: Sorry, I meant formed by the subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$. I mixed up $B_k$ with $B_n$.

Answer (score 0):

This has a problem, take $n = 1,$ then there should be $1^k=1$ but is clear that for a set of length $k$ there are $2^k$ so i think you should add the constraint in the multichain that $t_n = [k].$
**Hint:** $$[n]^{[k]}=\{f:[k]\longrightarrow [n]\},$$ what if you take $f\in [n]^{[k]}$ and construct $(f^{-1}(1),f^{-1}(1)\cup f^{-1}(2),\cdots f^{-1}(1)\cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(n))$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you clarify a bit on the notation? Is $[k]$ denoting the elements $\{ 1, \dots, k \}$?

Comment: Yes sir, $[k]=\{1,2,\cdots , k\}.$ Do you see how to construct the function back?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm working on it. I think that $f^{-1} = [k]$, since we can choose any of the $k$ elements to form a length $1$ chain. For $f^{-1}(2)$ we should have all pairs, etc. If I'm wrong, I probably haven't understood the bijection you are hinting towards yet.

Comment: Not quite, what if you take a chain $t_1\subseteq t_2\subseteq \cdots \subseteq t_n=[k]$ and you say that $f(t_1)=1,f(t_2\setminus t_1)=2$ etc...